# HERE Geocoder Autocomplete API

Tags: here-api, here-autocomplete

I am using the HERE Geocoder Autocomplete API. It works perfectly well but I would like to know :

How can I specify a minimum matching level like "street" or "city" so it won't return me the result with a matchLevel of "state" or "county" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoder Autocomplete API currently doesn't support restriction at matchLevel. You can explain your usecase in detail so that we can suggest alternatives if possible.

Comment: Hi @Here I have a similar requirement. I am using the API and I want to only show get results where the matchLevel is City, right now it returns matchLevel county, districts, etc which I do not need. How do i restrict to only list cities?